# Проверка существования записи (строчки) в mysql

Tags: mysql

Как проверить в mysql существование записи без возврата результирующего набора?
Имеется запрос, к примеру:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1;")
```

Такой запрос вернет результирующий набор, а можно ли как-то просто проверить существование строки?

Comment: так это и будет проверка. Если вернул запись, значит она есть... если вернул ничего - значит записи нет... Или я вопрос не так понял?

Comment: Сервер с таким запросом вернет строку с результатом, а можно ли как то сделать, чтобы вернул или true или false?

Comment: `mysqli_query("SELECT count(id)>0 FROM table WHERE id = 1;")` будет ответ `True` или `False`

Comment: А если я вопрос иначе поставлю. Как правильно с точки зрения mysql проверить существование строки? И нужен ли в конце limit 1, если сравнение осуществляется по уникальному индексу?

Comment: а может мне кто-то объяснить в чем принципиальная разница? запрос вернет что-то, или именно `true/false`? Я не против... просто хочу понять... может тогда иначе проверки делать стану...

Comment: @cyadvert думаю автор сам не понимает для чего такая проверка нужна, если набора в результате нет, то и строчки нет, а если есть, то и строчка есть, а если он желает делать проверку перед тем как делать запрос на получение данных то это двойная нагрузка на базу, ну и еще одна причина по которой автор это хочет делать это незнание как сделать автоинкриментный ID, как то так

Comment: думаю автору самый подходяший это `mysql_num_rows`. как я понял у него `php`

Comment: Афтар знает что такое автоинкримент, составные индексы, ключи и как все это работает на уровне сервера mysql. Запрос query возвращает объект result, который в свою очередь содержит результат запроса. Зачем лишний раз, к примеру, память забивать, когда можно просто вернуть труе или фалсе

Comment: Mysqli_num_rows возвращает количество строк после получения результирующего набора

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Есть много вариантов для проверки. Выберите одного, кому что нравится

---

Используя команду `EXISTS`

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1)
```

[документация тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

---

Использование количество значений

```
$res = mysql_query('select count(*) FROM table WHERE id = 1') or die();
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    // Есть данные
}
else
{
    // нет данных
}
```

---

оператор `mysql_num_rows`

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);

if( $count > 0 ) {
  // Есть данные
} else {
    // нет данных
}
```

Comment: а чем просто `select 1 from table where id = 1 limit 1` не угодил? если id не ключ, можно много времени на проверку потратить

Comment: @BOPOH согласен, тоже хорошый вариант

Comment: Что означает одиница после select)

Comment: Saidolin, спасибо, по игзисту почитаю сейчас

Comment: @Панилипропал, 1 - константа, чтобы не тащить из базы реальные данные, когда они нам будут не нужны (особенно когда выбираются данные из разных таблиц). В вашем конкретном случае это будет лишним (т.к. id это ключ и он уникален), но ответы не только для вас, но и для других посетителей, а у них запросы могут быть очень сложными.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqli_query("SELECT Count(id) FROM table WHERE id = 1;")
```

Данный запрос вернет 1 если строка есть и 0 если ее нет, при условии, что id уникален

Comment: зачем гонять туда-сюда данные по mysql? если надо проверить, так и делайте: `select 1 from table where id = 1 limit 1`, теперь этот пример можно будет применить практически к любому запросу. А в вашем же случае, если поиск будет не по ключу, - запрос может очень и очень долго выполняться

Comment: @BOPOH а зачем вообще такой поиск тогда нужен если Id не ключь? Проверка уникальности? ну так на то она и уникальность чтоб эксепшен выдать

Comment: уникальность тоже ключ, "зачем нужен" - получение результирующего набора может занять очень много времени, даже если в итоге ничего не будет возвращено. Чтобы лишний раз не выполнять такие тяжелые запросы, можно выполнить его легкую версию и проверить, что данные действительно есть. И зачем находить все записи с id=1, если нас интересует только наличие хотя бы одной такой записи? А ведь count как раз ищет их все. Убрав count и добавив limit мы можем сэкономить кучу времени. А выбирая из таблицу 1 вместо реальных данных, мы просто экономим на перебрасывании данных при куче джойнов

Comment: В моем случае, ключ уникален

Comment: @BOPOH согласен