# Модифицировать или добавить запись если она существует

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Стоит задача модифицировать(переписать) значение записи если она существует, а если такой записи не существует, то добавить такую запись

Ищу наиболее простой, быстродействующий и корректный способ это сделать

Ниже привел пример плохого решения этой задачи с помощью кода *C#*, где перехватывал ошибку при попытке добавлении записи (nick использовал как primary key, поэтому возникает ошибка с существованием записи с таким значением)

```
// добавление
try
{
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Money ('nick', 'money') values ('StriBog45' , '300')";
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SQLiteException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    // модификация
    try
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Money SET money = 600 WHERE nick = 'StriBog45'; ";
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
catch (SQLiteException xex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + xex.Message);
}
```

Есть идея сделать через if else внутри SQL команды, но тогда выполняется дополнительный поиск exist, что возможно замедляет работу, что-то вроде

```
if(exists(nick = 'StriBog45'))
UPDATE Money SET money = 600 WHERE nick = 'StriBog45'
Else
INSERT INTO Money ('nick', 'money') values ('StriBog45' , '300')
```

Команда `Insert into` проверяет ведь на повтор *primary key*, значит она уже использует в себе подобие exist, мне кажется этим можно как то воспользоваться

Среди *[Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461889/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-mysql)* находил такой вариант, но требует вводить дополнительные переменные и весьма объёмный

```
$res = mysql_query('select count(*) FROM table WHERE id = 1') or die();
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    // Есть данные
}
else
{
    // нет данных
}
```

Comment: А что вы видите плохого в вашем подходе ? Тут собственно только 2 варианта: или как у вас, ловим ошибку и потом update. Или сначала даем update, смотрим количество модифицированных записей (Не знаю как в c#, обычно это параметр ответа или соединения с названием affected_rows) и если вернуло 0, то даем insert. Но если работа многопоточная или кто то еще может обратится к той же БД, то во втором случае есть риск что между попыткой update и insert кто то успеет такую запись вставить. Вариант с предварительным count() еще хуже, вероятность коллизий еще выше

Comment: БД используется SQLite? Может тогда посмотреть в сторону upsert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для SQLite можно воспользоваться специальным синтаксисом UPSERT, если версия 3.24.0 или выше:

```
INSERT INTO Money ('nick', 'money')
VALUES('StriBog45' , '300')
ON CONFLICT(nick) DO UPDATE SET
  money=600;
```

В случае ранних версий можно воспользоваться конструкцией:

```
-- сначала попытка обновления существующей записи
UPDATE Money SET money=600 WHERE nick='StriBog45';
-- потом уже попытка вставки записи
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Money ('nick', 'money') VALUES ('StriBog45', 300);
```

Comment: Ответ на галку, плюсую.

Answer (score 3):

В mysql есть такая удобная вещь, как INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - как раз то, что вы хотите. И в sqlite она [есть с версии 3.24.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2717590/5752652).

Подробнее можете почитать в документации, есть некоторые отличия в синтаксисе:

- [документация по синтаксису UPSERT для sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)
- [документация по синтаксису INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE для mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Тут немного вариантов, либо вы проверяете существование записи и соответсвенно выполняете INSERT/UPDATE или используйте REPLACE, но тогда вы будете переписывать ВСЕ данные, и это может быть не совсем хорошо.